# Simple java Application build on Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I am building my simple java application which has some JAR dependencies. The build script is given below. It builds fine if I use the command, `gradle mainjar`. However, If I use `gradle build` , the build works fine but I get `ClassNotFoundException` on running , indicating that JAR files were not linked properly.

I understand the lines which I have wrote under `mainjar` tasks, but how do I cause them to be executed even with normal `build` task.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin:'application'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }



    }
     mainjar
}

jar {
  manifest { attributes 'Main-Class': 'in.co.madhur.wunderjava.Main' }
}

mainClassName = "in.co.madhur.wunderjava.Main"

task mainjar(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}}

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'in.co.madhur.wunderjava.Main'
    }
}



dependencies {

    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.3.0-rc1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.0-rc1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.3.0-rc1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.5.0'
}

dependencies {

    runtime 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.3.0-rc1'
    runtime 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.0-rc1'
    runtime 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.3.0-rc1'
    runtime 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.5.0'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `application` plugin uses the Jar built by the `jar` task, not the one built by your `mainjar` task. Hence the line `task mainjar(type: Jar) {` should be replaced with `jar {`. Also, it isn't necessary to repeat `compile` dependencies under `runtime`, and `configurations.compile.collect { zipTree(it) }` should be `configurations.runtime.collect { zipTree(it) }`. (This will start to make a difference once you have `runtime` dependencies that aren't also `compile` dependencies.)

Answer (score 2):

try to add

```
build.dependsOn mainjar
```

at the end of your file